# Detect if there is a modal form showing

Tags: forms, error-handling, vb6, modal-dialog

Is there some method of detecting if there is a modal form showing in my VB6 application.

I want to show another form modally if there is a modal form showing and modeless if there isn't a modal form showing.

I know I can do some error handling to detect this and show modally if the error occurs:

```
Public Sub ShowFormModeless(frm As Form, Optional ownerForm As Form = Nothing)
    On Error GoTo ShowModal
    Call frm.Show(, ownerForm)
    Exit Sub
ShowModal:
    Call frm.Show(vbModal, ownerForm)
End Sub
```

But I want to be able to detect this without the error being thrown.

Comment: This makes an interesting read but it suggests its not possible http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?723669-Detect-modal-form

Answer (score 1):

Try checking `App.NonModalAllowed`. Note that this property does not detect modal forms being shown from other (than current module) projects, i.e. if your application consists of main executable and several ActiveX dlls each of these projects will have a separate `App` object and `Forms` collection.

The result is that if a dll is showing a modal form only its own project's `App.NonModalAllowed` is flagged. So once again, `App.NonModalAllowed` is not a process-wide flag but a per project one.

Note that this flag tracks VB6 only forms, so if you are using API dialogs (open/save file, color picker, etc) this does not enter VB6 runtime's modal loop, so nothing is flagged.

If you application is a single exe then using this flag works as expected.

Comment: Thanks - this method doesn't seem to return the correct value for me though even in a test project with three forms.